# regex to find a pattern in a string and replace it with another pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regex to find a pattern in a string and replace it with another pattern

I want to change the `_` to `-` but only either side of numbers in between two text sections

Specifically, I have a pattern like:

```py
original = "first_part_1234_this_is_the_second_part"
```

and would like:

```py
desired = "first_part-1234-this_is_the_second_part"
```

i.e. keeping `_` in the first and second parts of the string.

I can use `()[_]\d*[_]()` to get the numbers in the middle of the string and

```py
desired = re.sub(r"()[_](\d*)[_]()", r"-\2-", original)
```

gives me `'first_part-this_is_the_second_part'`, i.e. identifies the numbers and replaces the first `_` with `-`.

I've not used regex before, and can't work out how to replace the pattern with another pattern.

Comment: *Capture* the digit matching pattern and then *backreference* the value using `r"\1"`.

Comment: @AlbinPaul the OP doesn't want to replace ALL occurrences of `_`, and it not clear how many `_`s there are in the first part (or even if their number is fixed).

Comment: looked into [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) and this:  `desired = re.sub(r"()[_]\d*[_]()", r"-\2-", original)` seems to work.